# Usage of "could"

Tags: word-usage, modal-verbs

I know that "could" is used for **past ability** but also I see some other sentences like "Could you please..." or something like this which actually doesn't mean an ability in the past.

What are the other kinds of usage for "could"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Could* is used to express unreal meaning, possibility and ability, but, when used in a question, it also offers a more polite way than *can* to ask permission.

Comment: Afshin: **Could** you have picked a more difficult word to explain? Even if I **could** list all the ways the word _'could'_ **could** be used, I don't think they **could** all fit in just one comment; it is a very flexible word. **Could** you ask an easier question next time? (No need to really answer those questions; I'm just providing a few examples of the different usages Barrie mentions.)